# error c2008: '.': unexpected in macro definition in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have a legacy code where is defined a macro

```
#ifndef RTW_HEADER_Export_gain.ads_h_
```

VS2019 report the error

```
error c2008: '.': unexpected in macro definition
```

According with the C standard, MINGW is able to compile the same code.
Is there an option to relax how visual studio will manage the macro name ?

Comment: Just fix the macro to not have `.` in it?

Comment: So, yay? We discovered a non compliant preprocessor? I'm guessing that VS2019 is taking a C++ approach to macros, in which an operator like `.` cannot be part of the name

Comment: Are you sure VS knows that it's C, not C++?

Comment: @TimRandall, C does not permit '.' to appear in identifiers either, unless as an extension.  But inasmuch as the `.` in particular is a C operator when it appears unquoted outside of a floating-point constant, I'm having trouble seeing how a conforming implementation could accept those in identifiers -- even macro identifiers.

Comment: I do not want to change the code, is there any tips ? MINGW compile without any issue !

Comment: The macro is just a guard against double inclusion

#ifndef RTW_HEADER_Export_gain.ads_h_
#define RTW_HEADER_Export_gain.ads_h_
#include "rtwtypes.h"

typedef struct {
  real_T out1;
  real_T out2;
} BusOutput;

#endif

Comment: Except gcc/mingw _doesn't_ accept it, it compiles with several warnings. I tried on a very old version gcc/mingw 4.9.1 and even that one gives correct diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard, the identifier `RTW_HEADER_Export_gain.ads_h_` is not valid.

> [**Identifier**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier)
>
> An identifier is an arbitrarily long sequence of digits, underscores, lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and Unicode characters specified using \u and \U escape notation (since C99). A valid identifier must begin with a non-digit character (Latin letter, underscore, or Unicode non-digit character (since C99)). Identifiers are case-sensitive (lowercase and uppercase letters are distinct).

In short, an identifier cannot contain an operator.
Look at the following example, what is that in your opinion:

```
my_obj.value
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and to highlight that also MINGW provide a warning !!!! I already provide the information to mathworks to fix the generated wrong code ! Do you know if exist an option in visual studio to tolerate the error and mimic the same result of mingw ?

Comment: I would say that tolerating errors or warnings is never a good idea. If the code contains errors or something else which the compiler warns about, the right choice is always to fix the specific issue and not to shut up the compiler (or IDE). So, if you want to silence your environment, you have to disable the error checks (again, not advised to do so).

Comment: Fully agree on your suggestion to fix the problem, and mathworks is in the process in doing that. In the mean time is there an option on VS2019 to silince this specific error on macro name ?

Comment: No. The only thing you can do is: set **C_Cpp: Error Squiggles** to **Disabled** (_Controls whether suspected compile errors detected by the IntelliSense engine will be reported back to the editor._). Other than that, i have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

> According with the C standard, MINGW is able to compile the same code.

That's nonsense. Don't go making such statements when you have no clue what you are talking about. Quote the standard.

This is what the formal grammar actually says (C17 6.10):

> `# ifndef` *identifier* *new-line* *group*<sub>opt</sub>

Where identifiers are specified in chapter 6.4.2 to only contain the symbols quoted below:

> *nondigit:* one of
> _ a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> *digit:* one of
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> /--/
>
> An identifier is a sequence of nondigit characters (including the underscore _, the lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and other characters) and digits, ...

---

Now the reason why "it compiles" in gcc/mingw is because it is using lax non-standard mode by default. Still it does not compile cleanly, you ignored these warnings:

> warning: missing whitespace after the macro name
> warning: extra tokens at end of #ifndef directive

Compiling with warnings doesn't mean that something is valid C. See [What must a C compiler do when it finds an error?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277340).
If you wish to get an error when compiling invalid C, you should use `gcc -std=c17 -pedantic-errors` (or -std=c11 for older Mingw).

So what does your code actually do when you compile with lax settings? Using `.` in identifiers is no gcc non-standard extension I know of. The #ifndef apparently only checks the `RTW_HEADER_Export_gain` part. Try this:

```
#define RTW_HEADER_Export_gain.bananas
#ifdef RTW_HEADER_Export_gain.ads_h_
  puts("RTW_HEADER_Export_gain.ads_h_ is definitely defined!");
#endif
```

This prints `RTW_HEADER_Export_gain.ads_h_ is definitely defined!` when I run it on gcc/mingw. So unfortunately it would appear that your old legacy code is full of latent bugs.

Comment: Further study: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)